# FullCalendar: Using the script in the construction of <body>

Tags: html, fullcalendar

If you make a call script in the construction of `<head>` - then it works, but if its cause in the construction of `<body>` - it does not work: (

**Work:**

```
<html>
<head>
..
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   events: [
    {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }
   ]
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Not work:**

```
<html>
<head>
..
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   events: [
    {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }
   ]
  });
 });
</script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me what I am doing wrong? ..

Answer (score 0):

That certainly is surprising! Are you sure you copy-and-pasted correctly? The only explanation that I can see immediately is that it's because the DOM element `#calendar` isn't loaded yet or something like that but jQuery shouldn't execute `$(document).ready` until every DOM element is loaded so it's definitely weird.

Your problem is most likely browser non-deterministic meaning it'll most likely work differently in different browsers between refreshes.

Can you try removing all the `fullCalendar` code from within `$(document).ready(` and instead just have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('calendar'));
});
```

Try that INSIDE the head and outside and see what difference it makes.